# cannot import name path pycall python

Tags: python-2.7

where do i find the solution to this ?

is in the missing dependencies or in the script?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pycall.callfile import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pycall-2.3.0-py2.6.egg/pycall/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .callfile import CallFile
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pycall-2.3.0-py2.6.egg/pycall/callfile.py", line 11, in <module>
    from path import path
ImportError: cannot import name path
```

Comment: Have you ran `pip install path.py`?

Comment: yes i have ran pip install path.py, but from root.

Comment: oh yeah please forgive, im a total noob in this